# Additional DNS name for AWS S3 hosted website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have a working S3 hosted website abc.example.com and a Route 53 A record abc.example.com & [www.abc.example.com](http://www.abc.example.com) and it works fine.

However, I want to create another Route53 A record named xyz.example.com that should point to the same S3 hosted website. To achieve this:

1. Created a CNAME xyz.example.com ---> abc.example.com but I get error saying that the DNS name and Bucket name don't match.
2. Created a CNAME / A record Aliases as xyz.example.com ---> abc.example.com but this does not work either.

Could anyone help in resolving this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this redirection by doing the following:

1. Create a new route53 A record as xyz.example.com that points to alias target s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com.
2. Create a new bucket xyz.example.com
3. Enabled static website hosting on this bucket but redirected it to abc.example.com

Now when we type xyz.example.com it loads the abc.example.com website as desired.

If anyone has a better solution then they are most welcome. Thanks